# Bash, compare the a result awk '{print $1} with something and return awk '{print$2} if true

Tags: bash, for-loop, awk, printing

My File Looks like this:

```
    790 45.61.188.53
    494 45.61.188.95
```

I need to compare the first  one for example 790 with something else and then print the second one.

So my code actually look like this:

```
c=$(cat $IPS | sed '/^$/d' | sort -rn | uniq -c | sort -rn | awk '{print $1}' | head -5 >> $CFILE)
i=$(cat $IPS | sed '/^$/d' | sort -rn | uniq -c | sort -rn | awk '{print $2}' |head -5)


for count in `cat $CFILE`
do
    if (( $count > 100 ));then
        echo "$i"
    fi
done
```

But the return output is :

```
45.61.188.53
45.61.188.95
20.230.214.19
45.61.187.215
78.142.63.3
45.61.188.53
45.61.188.95
20.230.214.19
45.61.187.215
78.142.63.3
45.61.188.53
45.61.188.95
20.230.214.19
45.61.187.215
78.142.63.3
45.61.188.53
45.61.188.95
20.230.214.19
45.61.187.215
78.142.63.3

and so on
```

I assume that this is normal behavior for the for loop but I cannot understand how can I do it using something different. Maybe arrays would be useful ?

Comment: What are you expecting `echo "$i"` to do other than output all 5 rows in `$i`?

Comment: Is the file at the top `$IPS` or `$CFILE`?

Comment: Well , I thought that if I echo $i based on the pattern that I set in the file it would only display the IP that is matching the IF statement before that. So Assuming that $i is the second row and $c(CFILE) is the first row, so If the First row match the statement, then display the second row. That is the point that I am trying to reach.

Comment: Why did you think that? Is it supposed to magically guess that there's a relationship between the loop iteration and the lines in `$i`?

Comment: You could use arrays, then you can loop through the array indexes. After testing `${array1[i]}` you can echo `${array2[i]}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this entirely in `awk`

```
awk '$1 > 100 { print $2 }' "$CFILE"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
{m,g}awk '$!NF = $(NF *= 100<+$_)'
```